# Is pip install failing with errors referencing strange urls?

Tags: pip

I'm having an issue installing pyhdfs via pip, it was working earlier today. The error is very unusual with some URLs to different websites like CNN and dollarshaveclub. See below:

Is it possible there is an issue with servers pip uses? I see another post on the AWS forums today with the same issue. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=978481&#978481

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gr9j0e/pywebhdfs/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gr9j0e/pywebhdfs/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6LimgJ
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-gr9j0e/pywebhdfs/
    Complete output (33 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-gr9j0e/pywebhdfs/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        pbr=True)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 269, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 826, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1092, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1104, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 651, in easy_install
        not self.always_copy, self.local_index
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 615, in fetch_distribution
        return dist.clone(location=self.download(dist.location, tmpdir))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 531, in download
        found = self._download_url(scheme.group(1), spec, tmpdir)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 772, in _download_url
        return self._attempt_download(url, filename)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 778, in _attempt_download
        headers = self._download_to(url, filename)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 678, in _download_to
        fp = self.open_url(strip_fragment(url))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 720, in open_url
        raise DistutilsError('%s %s' % (url, msg))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/e2/8cb5e718a3a63e8c22677fde5e3d8d18d12a551a1bbd4557217e38a97ad0/pbr-5.5.1.tar.gz#sha256=5fad80b613c402d5b7df7bd84812548b2a61e9977387a80a5fc5c396492b13c9 hostname 'files.pythonhosted.org' doesn't match either of 'r.ssl.fastly.net', '*.catchpoint.com', '*.cnn.io', '*.dollarshaveclub.com', '*.eater.com', '*.fastly.picmonkey.com', '*.files.saymedia-content.com', '*.ft.com', '*.meetupstatic.com', '*.nfl.com', '*.pagar.me', '*.picmonkey.com', '*.realself.com', '*.sbnation.com', '*.shakr.com', '*.streamable.com', '*.surfly.com', '*.theverge.com', '*.thrillist.com', '*.vox-cdn.com', '*.vox.com', '*.voxmedia.com', 'eater.com', 'ft.com', 'i.gse.io', 'picmonkey.com', 'realself.com', 'static.wixstatic.com', 'streamable.com', 'surfly.com', 'theverge.com', 'vox-cdn.com', 'vox.com', 'www.joyent.com'
```